# SQL: Select a record by name field and all records having the same address

Tags: mysql

What SQL query would find a record by name, and also all records having the same address but possibly different names?

I have a voter registration database, and when I look up an individual, I would also like to see who else is registered at the address.

My database is called voters and the table in it is called extract. If I want to find someone by name, I write

```
SELECT * FROM voters.extract WHERE first_name = "John" AND last_name = "Doe";
```

If I want to find someone by address, I write

```
SELECT * FROM voters.extract WHERE street_num = "100"
AND addr_unit = "A" AND street_name = "Main Street" AND town = "My Town";
```

So, what I want to do is find someone by name, get the address, and then find everyone having that same address.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `join` or `in` or `exists`:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM (SELECT e.*
      FROM voters.extract e
      WHERE first_name = 'John' AND last_name = 'Doe'
     ) en JOIN
     voters.extract e
     USING (street_num, addr_unit, street_name, town);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the usual (and probably the fastest) solution for your question:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM voters.extract a
INNER JOIN voters.extract n
  ON a.street_num = n.street_num
    AND a.addr_unit = n.addr_unit
    AND a.street_name = n.street_name
    AND a.town = n.town
WHERE n.first_name = "John" AND n.last_name = "Doe"
```

The query `JOIN`s the table `extract`, aliased as `a` (from "address") against itself, aliased as `n` (from "name"). The `JOIN` condition matches each row from `a` with all the rows from `n` having the same address. The `WHERE` condition filters only the rows from `n` having the desired name. The `SELECT` clause returns only the rows from `a` after filtering.

In plain English, the `WHERE` clause identifies the voters having the name you provided, the `JOIN` identifies all the voters that have the same address as the one found by `WHERE` and the `SELECT` clause returns only the information found by the `JOIN` clause.

Comment: Thanks. This looks similar to something I did before, but which resulted in 9 duplicate records; something I discovered after noticing they all had the same first and last name! Your answer gave the results I was looking for.